Very Old (50's?) Cowboy/Old West Movie Memory - stumping me!
My only memory of this movie is the briefest of snippets.
It was shown on TV in the UK at least 40 years ago. I saw it in B&W but that doesn't actually mean the movie was.
It is about cowboys, or at least the "Old West" (maybe Civil War, but that's not what I have in mind). Given the time when I saw it, it must have been an American production.
The scene is: some dude either has, or has been accused, of somehow betraying the other dudes he is a part of.
And in a saloon (or similar place) this subject comes up, and everyone in the room gets up, and while he is protesting his innocence (of whatever the thing was) he is stabbed to death (off camera) then one of the killers wipes his bloodied knife on the cloth of the card table, where an ace of spades just happens to be sitting face up.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
